# Padding Zero to Chapter Heading in Table of Contents in amsbook class

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, books, amsbook, fmtcount

It is possible to pad zero to chapter heading in table of contents. It is getting reflected in Chapter pages but not in `table of contents` Here is the code.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,fmtcount}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
 {\thechapter}
{\expandafter\ifx\@chapapp\appendixname\else\ifnum\value{chapter}<10 0\fi\fi\thechapter}
{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}
\chapter{Second}
\chapter{Third}
\end{document}
```

However the same is not reflected in table of contents. I want the chapter numbers as `01 First`, `02 Second`, `03 Third` and so on. How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the counter representation - `\thechapter` - to prepend a `0`; there exists a `\two@digits` kernel macro that does this.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\ifnum\value{chapter}<10 0\fi\arabic{chapter}}
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\two@digits{\value{chapter}}}
%\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\chapter{Second}
\chapter{Third}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I could say something about using `\value{chapter}` instead of `\c@chapter`, but decided not to.